# Query selector for nodes not containing blockquote

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, selectors-api

I'm trying to figure out a selector for the following markup. I want all nodes, *except the node which contains a blockquote*. The `<blockquote>` will always be an immediate child of a `<div>` which will be an immediate child of the `<body>` tag.

**Example HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <!-- Lots of HTML -->
</ul>
<div>
    <p>
        <!-- Lots of other HTML -->
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <blockquote>Some text I don't care about</blockquote>
</div>
```

**Expected Result:**

```
<ul><!-- Lots of HTML --></ul>
<div><p><!-- Lots of other HTML --></p></div>
```

**Attempted Selector:**

```
document.querySelectorAll("body > :not(div > blockquote)")
```

I tried the above, but I can't put an immediate child selector inside the `:not()` selector. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S5W3F/) of the failed attempt.

**I am not currently and nor can I use jQuery.**

Comment: Siblings are elements that exist alongside one another, in your case the `<ul>` and the two `<div>`s that follow it are siblings. The `<blockquote>` is a *child* of its `<div>` which in turn is a *child* of `<body>`, and `>` is the child selector. (The immediate sibling selector is `+`.)

Comment: @BoltClock Heh, too late in the day! Will update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this natively. There is no way of filtering elements by their children in any current selector specification. (This may come in a future selectors specification, however.)

You will therefore need to do it by doing the filtering yourself. This isn't particularly difficult. One way would be by selecting all the relevant elements, then filtering out the ones you don't want:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("body > *"))
    .filter(function(el) {
        return !el.querySelector(':scope > blockquote');
    })
```

[(jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/S5W3F/2/)

This turns the selection into an array, then uses the [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to get rid of all those that contain a `blockquote` element.

Obviously this has far worse performance than a native selector, but it is the only way to do what you want in current JS.

As BoltClock rightly points out, `:scope` is not yet an official standard. I was lulled into a false sense of security by the fact that Chrome *does* support it: other browsers as yet do not. If you want to exclude any top level element that contains a `blockquote` element at any level, the best way to do this is:

```
return !el.querySelector('blockquote');
```

Comment: @tenbits I'm not sure if this will make a difference to the OP, but yes, that is the precise wording of the question. So... updated answer.

Comment: removed my comment, before your comment) As your edited solution was much better with the ':scope' ;)

Comment: It might still be a little early to make use of `:scope` yet. (Note that `:scope` comes from the same spec that the subject indicator does (Selectors 4), but considering its appeal, chances are that browsers will implement `:scope` first.)

Comment: Updated one is perfect. There may be nested `<blockquote>` elements which I'll need to keep. I'm targeting the latest version of Chrome here, so :scope should be fine.